# One firestore for two Firebase projects　(react,javascirpt,firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Currently I'm working on two react projects
The first is a chat project on the operator side
The second is a chat project on the user side
I want to use different firebase hosting for each, but I want to use only one side of the firestore and let them chat.

Comment: Please tell me what kind of description should be made at this time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Firebase documentation on [using multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application), which contains this example of how to configure a secondary project in a web app:

```
// The following fields are REQUIRED:
//  - Project ID
//  - App ID
//  - API Key
var secondaryAppConfig = {
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    appId: "<APP_ID>",
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    // databaseURL: "...",
    // storageBucket: "...",
};
```

And then:

```
// Initialize another app with a different config
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
// Access services, such as firestore
// secondaryApp.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is have Hosting for two separate apps, you don't need to have separate Firebase projects.

It's a lot simpler to just add another site to Firebase Hosting. There's some documentation on it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites